# Is there DeepZoom support for OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I am developing an OpenLayers 3 app, but I need it to use Microsoft's proprietary DeepZoom file format for its image pyramid. I am surprised to see that this does not already exist. Has this been done, or am I just going to have to write it?

Answer (score 1):

DeepZoom is not available. However, there is support for Zoomify, which serves the same purpose.